# How To Add Approvers Workflow Comments In an Email?

Tags: 2010

I have a three-step Designer 2010 approval workflow.  If any one of the approvers rejects the approval request I would like to add their comments in a separate email.  I can’t figure out what lookup string to use in the email message. Thank you.